# Counting unique characters between delimiters across a single Cell multiple times and then applying it to multiple rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, stringr, gsub

Having a little difficulty phrasing this question so please bear with me.

I have an `x` x 7 dataframe, where the last column is a `numpy` array converted into something R can read.

Unfortunately, the last column varies in the length and number of "cells" (aka, bracket pairs `[]`) in the column. Further, the values within each "cell" (aka commas within brackets+1 `[,,,]`) is also variable.

Something like the following:

```
ID  Binary  Continuous  date1   date2   character   numpy_array
101 0   0   20-01-01    21-01-01    CHAR    [0.012110, 0.11211022, 0.110101, 0.102020102, 0.111, 0.10, 0.11, 0.10220, 0.011202220, 0.120220, 0.211011], [0.10201011202, 0.220, 0.02010]
102 0   2   21-01-01    22-01-01    CHAR    [0.11012, 0.11303013202, 0.1012012010213, 0.303320301, 0.1312, 0.0203021], [0.02310, 0.111, 0.2023, 0.01120, 0.03201120, 0.101211202, 0.012220, 0.1130301030, 0.013], [0.22123020, 0.21010312, 0.013032020, 0.20301303233, 0.3010231323, 0.033303, 0.131021022020]
103 0   5   22-01-01    23-01-01    CHAR    [0.0232030302, 0.22, 0.0210, 0.32101011013, 0.2011230, 0.301110, 0.10, 0.012133, 0.202301, 0.10222210, 0.103221, 0.102120220, 0.21030, 0.31030102, 0.123], [0.1032230, 0.0323101, 0.10132120, 0.102033, 0.312010, 0.11310221201, 0.2, 0.3302, 0.311, 0.231203020, 0.01312123, 0.2303210301, 0.111230320, 0.31220132, 0.023101312202, 0.133023], [0.310330, 0.20301020, 0.210303, 0.213011030, 0.0302030332, 0.1322222, 0.1202302301, 0.33220220, 0.21332, 0.12103030, 1.301, 0.1232033], [0.01010303012, 0.3010330220, 0.10303230, 0.11030, 0.130102, 0.313121, 0.2113101020, 0.121010, 0.0320221033, 0.0303303, 0.123301, 0.3013021, 0.31031022102, 0.21013112021, 0.0102101]
```

The number, position, and values of these "cells" need to be structured in such a way in the final output that I can (row-wise)summarize these values by `ID` (there are multiple entries per person).

I'd like to take the structuring of the `numpy` array into account in a final output, and to try and do so, I'd like to count the number of unique "cells" within the `numpy_array` variable as well as the number of values within each bracket pairing by row. Both to record the number of bracket parings and within-bracket values for later analysis, and to generate some unique columns structured in such a manner that (row-wise)summarize of these values by `ID` (there are multiple entries by `ID`)

Something like this:

```
ID  Binary  Continuous  date1   date2   character   Cells   Values_by_cell  Cell_1_Value_1  Cell_1_Value_2  Cell_1_Value_3  Cell_1_Value_4  Cell_1_Value_5  Cell_1_Value_6  Cell_1_Value_7  Cell_1_Value_8  Cell_1_Value_9  Cell_1_Value_10 Cell_1_Value_11 Cell_1_Value_12 Cell_1_Value_13 Cell_1_Value_14 Cell_1_Value_15 Cell_1_Value_16 Cell_2_Value_1  Cell_2_Value_2  Cell_2_Value_3  Cell_2_Value_4  Cell_2_Value_5  Cell_2_Value_6  Cell_2_Value_7  Cell_2_Value_8  Cell_2_Value_9  Cell_2_Value_10 Cell_2_Value_11 Cell_2_Value_12 Cell_2_Value_13 Cell_2_Value_14 Cell_2_Value_15 Cell_2_Value_16 Cell_3_Value_1  Cell_3_Value_2  Cell_3_Value_3  Cell_3_Value_4  Cell_3_Value_5  Cell_3_Value_6  Cell_3_Value_7  Cell_3_Value_8  Cell_3_Value_9  Cell_3_Value_10 Cell_3_Value_11 Cell_3_Value_12 Cell_3_Value_13 Cell_3_Value_14 Cell_3_Value_15 Cell_3_Value_16 Cell_4_Value_1  Cell_4_Value_2  Cell_4_Value_3  Cell_4_Value_4  Cell_4_Value_5  Cell_4_Value_6  Cell_4_Value_7  Cell_4_Value_8  Cell_4_Value_9  Cell_4_Value_10 Cell_4_Value_11 Cell_4_Value_12 Cell_4_Value_13 Cell_4_Value_14 Cell_4_Value_15 Cell_4_Value_16
101 0   0   20-01-01    21-01-01    CHAR    2   [11,3]  0.01211 0.11211022  0.110101    0.102020102 0.111   0.1 0.11    0.1022  0.01120222  0.12022 0.211011    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0.102010112 0.22    0.0201  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
102 0   2   21-01-01    22-01-01    CHAR    3   [6,9,7] 0.11012 0.113030132 0.101201201 0.303320301 0.1312  0.0203021   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0.0231  0.111   0.2023  0.0112  0.0320112   0.101211202 0.01222 0.113030103 0.013   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0.2212302   0.21010312  0.01303202  0.203013032 0.301023132 0.033303    0.131021022 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
103 0   5   22-01-01    23-01-01    CHAR    4   [14,16,12,15]   0.02320303  0.22    0.021   0.32101011  0.201123    0.30111 0.1 0.012133    0.202301    0.1022221   0.103221    0.10212022  0.2103  0.31030102  0.123   NA  0.103223    0.0323101   0.1013212   0.102033    0.31201 0.113102212 0.2 0.3302  0.311   0.23120302  0.01312123  0.23032103  0.11123032  0.31220132  0.023101312 0.133023    0.31033 0.2030102   0.210303    0.21301103  0.030203033 0.1322222   0.12023023  0.3322022   0.21332 0.1210303   1.301   0.1232033   NA  NA  NA  NA  0.01010303  0.301033022 0.1030323   0.1103  0.130102    0.313121    0.211310102 0.12101 0.032022103 0.0303303   0.123301    0.3013021   0.310310221 0.21013112  0.0102101   NA
```

I initially tried to get a single instance summary with something like the following:

```
table(unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(df[,ncol(df)][1], '\\[.*?\\]')))
```

That I could convert into a function and then apply to all the rows, but the syntax necessary to count the number of commas+1 in between each `[]` instance isn't clear to me (this command just returns *EVERYTHING* between the brackets.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

*Appended for ease of access at commenter @LMc's request:

> dput(df)

```
structure(list(ID = 101:103, Binary = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Continuous = c(0L, 
2L, 5L), date1 = c("20-01-01", "21-01-01", "22-01-01"), date2 = c("21-01-01", 
"22-01-01", "23-01-01"), character = c("CHAR", "CHAR", "CHAR"
), numpy_array = c("[0.012110, 0.11211022, 0.110101, 0.102020102, 0.111, 0.10, 0.11, 0.10220, 0.011202220, 0.120220, 0.211011], [0.10201011202, 0.220, 0.02010]", 
"[0.11012, 0.11303013202, 0.1012012010213, 0.303320301, 0.1312, 0.0203021], [0.02310, 0.111, 0.2023, 0.01120, 0.03201120, 0.101211202, 0.012220, 0.1130301030, 0.013], [0.22123020, 0.21010312, 0.013032020, 0.20301303233, 0.3010231323, 0.033303, 0.131021022020]", 
"[0.0232030302, 0.22, 0.0210, 0.32101011013, 0.2011230, 0.301110, 0.10, 0.012133, 0.202301, 0.10222210, 0.103221, 0.102120220, 0.21030, 0.31030102, 0.123], [0.1032230, 0.0323101, 0.10132120, 0.102033, 0.312010, 0.11310221201, 0.2, 0.3302, 0.311, 0.231203020, 0.01312123, 0.2303210301, 0.111230320, 0.31220132, 0.023101312202, 0.133023], [0.310330, 0.20301020, 0.210303, 0.213011030, 0.0302030332, 0.1322222, 0.1202302301, 0.33220220, 0.21332, 0.12103030, 1.301, 0.1232033], [0.01010303012, 0.3010330220, 0.10303230, 0.11030, 0.130102, 0.313121, 0.2113101020, 0.121010, 0.0320221033, 0.0303303, 0.123301, 0.3013021, 0.31031022102, 0.21013112021, 0.0102101]"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(df)` into your question so it is easier to access your data?

Comment: Hopefully that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `tidyverse` packages:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(cells = str_split(numpy_array , "\\], \\["),
         values = map(cells, \(x) map(x, \(y) as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(y, "[0-9\\.]+"))))),
         character = lengths(values),
         cells = map(values, lengths)) |>
  unnest_longer(values) |>
  mutate(values = map(values, ~ set_names(.x, str_c("value", seq_along(.x))))) |>
  mutate(names = str_c("cell", row_number()), .by = cells) |>
  unnest_wider(values) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = names,
              names_glue = "{names}_{.value}",
              names_vary = "slowest",
              values_from = starts_with("value")
              ) |> 
  select(-numpy_array)
```

**How it works**

It is probably easiest if you try running this line-by-line to understand it in more detail.

Generally, the aim is to convert your column into a comparable R object. Then pivot into a wide data frame.

In this case, in the first mutate we convert `numpy_array` into a list-column, where the list contains numeric vectors. Along the way, we record `character` (eg the number of elements in each row) and `cells` the lengths of each row-wise list element.

At this point `values` looks like:

```r
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1] 0.01211000 0.11211022 0.11010100 0.10202010 0.11100000 0.10000000 0.11000000 0.10220000 0.01120222 0.12022000 0.21101100

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0.1020101 0.2200000 0.0201000


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.1101200 0.1130301 0.1012012 0.3033203 0.1312000 0.0203021

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 0.0231000 0.1110000 0.2023000 0.0112000 0.0320112 0.1012112 0.0122200 0.1130301 0.0130000

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 0.22123020 0.21010312 0.01303202 0.20301303 0.30102313 0.03330300 0.13102102
.
.
.
```

Next, we `unnest_longer`. This gives a structure such that each row contains a "cell" (as you call it). In this structure we do a little formatting in the next two `mutate` statements to get ready to widen the data frame using `unnest_wider`:

1. We assign value names (eg value1, value2)
2. We assign cell names (eg cell1, cell2)

In the final two steps we widen the data frame how you requested.

**Output**

```
     ID Binary Continuous date1    date2  character cells cell1_value1 cell1_value2 cell1_value3 cell1_value4 cell1_value5 cell1_value6 cell1_value7 cell1_value8 cell1_value9
  <int>  <int>      <int> <chr>    <chr>      <int> <lis>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1   101      0          0 20-01-01 21-01…         2 <int>       0.0121        0.112        0.110        0.102        0.111       0.1            0.11       0.102        0.0112
2   102      0          2 21-01-01 22-01…         3 <int>       0.110         0.113        0.101        0.303        0.131       0.0203        NA         NA           NA     
3   103      0          5 22-01-01 23-01…         4 <int>       0.0232        0.22         0.021        0.321        0.201       0.301          0.1        0.0121       0.202 
# ℹ 55 more variables: cell1_value10 <dbl>, cell1_value11 <dbl>, cell1_value12 <dbl>, cell1_value13 <dbl>, cell1_value14 <dbl>, cell1_value15 <dbl>, cell1_value16 <dbl>,
#   cell2_value1 <dbl>, cell2_value2 <dbl>, cell2_value3 <dbl>, cell2_value4 <dbl>, cell2_value5 <dbl>, cell2_value6 <dbl>, cell2_value7 <dbl>, cell2_value8 <dbl>,
#   cell2_value9 <dbl>, cell2_value10 <dbl>, cell2_value11 <dbl>, cell2_value12 <dbl>, cell2_value13 <dbl>, cell2_value14 <dbl>, cell2_value15 <dbl>, cell2_value16 <dbl>,
#   cell3_value1 <dbl>, cell3_value2 <dbl>, cell3_value3 <dbl>, cell3_value4 <dbl>, cell3_value5 <dbl>, cell3_value6 <dbl>, cell3_value7 <dbl>, cell3_value8 <dbl>,
#   cell3_value9 <dbl>, cell3_value10 <dbl>, cell3_value11 <dbl>, cell3_value12 <dbl>, cell3_value13 <dbl>, cell3_value14 <dbl>, cell3_value15 <dbl>, cell3_value16 <dbl>,
#   cell4_value1 <dbl>, cell4_value2 <dbl>, cell4_value3 <dbl>, cell4_value4 <dbl>, cell4_value5 <dbl>, cell4_value6 <dbl>, cell4_value7 <dbl>, cell4_value8 <dbl>,
#   cell4_value9 <dbl>, cell4_value10 <dbl>, cell4_value11 <dbl>, cell4_value12 <dbl>, cell4_value13 <dbl>, cell4_value14 <dbl>, cell4_value15 <dbl>, cell4_value16 <dbl>
```

Comment: This seems to be working quite well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use `py_eval` from package `reticulate` to parse the python lists in `numpy_array`, and then `unnest` + `pivot_wider` the resulting dataframe. For example

```
options(dplyr.width = Inf)

library(reticulate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    mutate(numpy_array = lapply(numpy_array, py_eval)) %>%
    mutate(
        Cells = lengths(numpy_array),
        Values_by_cell = sapply(numpy_array, \(x) sprintf("[%s]", toString(lengths(x)))),
        .before = numpy_array
    ) %>%
    unnest(numpy_array) %>%
    mutate(Cell_ID = seq_len(n()), .by = ID:Values_by_cell, .before = numpy_array) %>%
    unnest(numpy_array) %>%
    mutate(Value_ID = seq_len(n()), .by = ID:Cell_ID, .before = numpy_array) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        values_from = numpy_array,
        names_from = c(Cell_ID, Value_ID),
        names_glue = "Cell_{Cell_ID}_Value_{Value_ID}"
    )
```

and you will obtain

```
# A tibble: 3 × 66
     ID Binary Continuous date1    date2    character Cells Values_by_cell
  <int>  <int>      <int> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <int> <chr>
1   101      0          0 20-01-01 21-01-01 CHAR          2 [11, 3]
2   102      0          2 21-01-01 22-01-01 CHAR          3 [6, 9, 7]
3   103      0          5 22-01-01 23-01-01 CHAR          4 [15, 16, 12, 15]
  Cell_1_Value_1 Cell_1_Value_2 Cell_1_Value_3 Cell_1_Value_4 Cell_1_Value_5
           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1         0.0121          0.112          0.110          0.102          0.111
2         0.110           0.113          0.101          0.303          0.131
3         0.0232          0.22           0.021          0.321          0.201
  Cell_1_Value_6 Cell_1_Value_7 Cell_1_Value_8 Cell_1_Value_9 Cell_1_Value_10
           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
1         0.1              0.11         0.102          0.0112           0.120
2         0.0203          NA           NA             NA               NA
3         0.301            0.1          0.0121         0.202            0.102
  Cell_1_Value_11 Cell_2_Value_1 Cell_2_Value_2 Cell_2_Value_3 Cell_2_Value_4
            <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1           0.211         0.102          0.22           0.0201        NA
2          NA             0.0231         0.111          0.202          0.0112
3           0.103         0.103          0.0323         0.101          0.102
  Cell_2_Value_5 Cell_2_Value_6 Cell_2_Value_7 Cell_2_Value_8 Cell_2_Value_9
           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1        NA              NA            NA              NA             NA
2         0.0320          0.101         0.0122          0.113          0.013
3         0.312           0.113         0.2             0.330          0.311
  Cell_3_Value_1 Cell_3_Value_2 Cell_3_Value_3 Cell_3_Value_4 Cell_3_Value_5
           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1         NA             NA            NA              NA            NA
2          0.221          0.210         0.0130          0.203         0.301
3          0.310          0.203         0.210           0.213         0.0302
  Cell_3_Value_6 Cell_3_Value_7 Cell_1_Value_12 Cell_1_Value_13 Cell_1_Value_14
           <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1        NA              NA              NA              NA              NA
2         0.0333          0.131          NA              NA              NA
3         0.132           0.120           0.102           0.210           0.310
  Cell_1_Value_15 Cell_2_Value_10 Cell_2_Value_11 Cell_2_Value_12
            <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1          NA              NA             NA               NA
2          NA              NA             NA               NA
3           0.123           0.231          0.0131           0.230
  Cell_2_Value_13 Cell_2_Value_14 Cell_2_Value_15 Cell_2_Value_16 Cell_3_Value_8
            <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>
1          NA              NA             NA               NA             NA
2          NA              NA             NA               NA             NA
3           0.111           0.312          0.0231           0.133          0.332
  Cell_3_Value_9 Cell_3_Value_10 Cell_3_Value_11 Cell_3_Value_12 Cell_4_Value_1
           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>
1         NA              NA               NA             NA            NA
2         NA              NA               NA             NA            NA
3          0.213           0.121            1.30           0.123         0.0101
  Cell_4_Value_2 Cell_4_Value_3 Cell_4_Value_4 Cell_4_Value_5 Cell_4_Value_6
           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1         NA             NA             NA             NA             NA
2         NA             NA             NA             NA             NA
3          0.301          0.103          0.110          0.130          0.313
  Cell_4_Value_7 Cell_4_Value_8 Cell_4_Value_9 Cell_4_Value_10 Cell_4_Value_11
           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1         NA             NA            NA              NA               NA
2         NA             NA            NA              NA               NA
3          0.211          0.121         0.0320          0.0303           0.123
  Cell_4_Value_12 Cell_4_Value_13 Cell_4_Value_14 Cell_4_Value_15
            <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1          NA              NA              NA             NA
2          NA              NA              NA             NA
3           0.301           0.310           0.210          0.0102
```

Comment: This would work quite well had I not already converted it from a numpy array to a list externally using a python script I had made. before importing it into R That said, will keep this in mind for when we do this again. Thanks so much!