# Flatten a numpy array and generate pandas columns based on array position

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance, apply

Apologies for cross posting on topics, but I'm looking to do a variation of something I did in R using python:
[Counting unique characters between delimiters across a single Cell multiple times and then applying it to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76822606/counting-unique-characters-between-delimiters-across-a-single-cell-multiple-time)

My original data looks something like this:

```
ID  Binary  Continuous  date1   date2   character   numpy_array
101 0   0   20-01-01    21-01-01    CHAR    array([[0.012110, 0.11211022, 0.110101, 0.102020102], [0.10201011202, 0.220, 0.02010, 0.10220]])
102 0   2   21-01-01    22-01-01    CHAR    array([[0.0232030302, 0.22, 0.0210, 0.32101011013, 0.2011230, 0.301110, 0.10, 0.012133], [0.1032230, 0.0323101, 0.10132120, 0.102033, 0.312010, 0.11310221201, 0.2, 0.3302], [0.310330, 0.20301020, 0.210303, 0.213011030, 0.0302030332, 0.1322222, 0.1202302301, 0.33220220], [0.01010303012, 0.3010330220, 0.10303230, 0.11030, 0.130102, 0.313121, 0.2113101020, 0.121010]])
103 0   5   22-01-01    23-01-01    CHAR    array([[0.11012, 0.11303013202, 0.1012012010213, 0.303320301, 0.1312, 0.0203021], [0.02310, 0.111, 0.2023, 0.01120, 0.03201120, 0.101211202], [0.22123020, 0.21010312, 0.013032020, 0.20301303233, 0.3010231323, 0.033303]])
```

Due to library conflicts between `reticulate`, `R/Studio`, and RHEL7, it I'm going to have to convert the `numpy` array in my data to `pandas` columns with positionally-aware variable names.

Something like the following:

```
ID  Binary  Continuous  date1   date2   character   array_dim   array_lengths   array_1_value_1 array_1_value_2 array_1_value_3 array_1_value_4 array_1_value_5 array_1_value_6 array_1_value_7 array_1_value_8 array_2_value_1 array_2_value_2 array_2_value_3 array_2_value_4 array_2_value_5 array_2_value_6 array_2_value_7 array_2_value_8 array_3_value_1 array_3_value_2 array_3_value_3 array_3_value_4 array_3_value_5 array_3_value_6 array_3_value_7 array_3_value_8 array_4_value_1 array_4_value_2 array_4_value_3 array_4_value_4 array_4_value_5 array_4_value_6 array_4_value_7 array_4_value_8
101 0   0   20-01-01    21-01-01    CHAR    2   [4,4]   0.012110    0.11211022  0.110101    0.102020102 NA  NA  NA  NA  0.10201011202   0.220   0.02010 0.10220 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
102 0   2   21-01-01    22-01-01    CHAR    4   [8,8,8,8]   0.0232030302    0.22    0.0210  0.32101011013   0.2011230   0.301110    0.10    0.012133    0.1032230   0.0323101   0.10132120  0.102033    0.312010    0.11310221201   0.2 0.3302  0.310330    0.20301020  0.210303    0.213011030 0.0302030332    0.1322222   0.1202302301    0.33220220  0.01010303012   0.301033022 0.1030323   0.1103  0.130102    0.313121    0.211310102 0.12101
103 0   5   22-01-01    23-01-01    CHAR    3   [6,6,6] 0.11012 0.11303013202   0.1012012010213 0.303320301 0.1312  0.0203021   NA  NA  0.02310 0.111   0.2023  0.01120 0.03201120  0.101211202 NA  NA  0.22123020  0.21010312  0.013032020 0.20301303233   0.3010231323    0.033303    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Where `array_dims` is the number of within `[]` vectors within the array for that row and column in the `pandas` dataframe, and `array_lengths` is the length of each of the total number of `numpy` vectors, and the rest of the columns in the `pandas` dataframe are the total number of values within the `numpy` position by its location within the `numpy` array relative to all the other arrays in the data.

Trying to flip it directly throws a function error:

```
out=pd.Dataframe(df['numpy_array'].iloc[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

But converting it to a `pd.Series` seems to work, but will require additional transposing and flattening which I feel can be done more efficiently (and without a loop using `apply` or something) than the way I'm doing it.

Some code to generate the sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':  [101,102,103],
        'Binary': [0,0,0],
        'Continuous': [0,2,5],
        'date1': ['20-01-01', '21-01-01', '22-01-01'],
        'date2': ['21-01-01', '22-01-01', '23-01-01'],
        'character': ['CHAR', 'CHAR', 'CHAR'],
        'numpy_array': [np.array([[0.012110, 0.11211022, 0.110101, 0.102020102], [0.10201011202, 0.220, 0.02010, 0.10220]]),np.array([[0.0232030302, 0.22, 0.0210, 0.32101011013, 0.2011230, 0.301110, 0.10, 0.012133], [0.1032230, 0.0323101, 0.10132120, 0.102033, 0.312010, 0.11310221201, 0.2, 0.3302], [0.310330, 0.20301020, 0.210303, 0.213011030, 0.0302030332, 0.1322222, 0.1202302301, 0.33220220], [0.01010303012, 0.3010330220, 0.10303230, 0.11030, 0.130102, 0.313121, 0.2113101020, 0.121010]]),np.array([[0.11012, 0.11303013202, 0.1012012010213, 0.303320301, 0.1312, 0.0203021], [0.02310, 0.111, 0.2023, 0.01120, 0.03201120, 0.101211202], [0.22123020, 0.21010312, 0.013032020, 0.20301303233, 0.3010231323, 0.033303]])]
        })
```

Comment: That seems like a complicated solution - if you're just trying to send a dataframe which doesn't contain any NumPy arrays, why not [convert the NumPy array to JSON and back](https://pynative.com/python-serialize-numpy-ndarray-into-json/)?

Comment: There's quite a few fields in this dataset (this is just a sample). With much longer values in each. I don't think writing each row to a JSON and then putting it back is a viable solution with regard to speed and resources in that regard.

Comment: From a performance perspective, if you have a column which is only defined for a single row, then Pandas must still allocate memory for every other row to have a value in that column. If one row contains an array with a thousand values, then all rows must have space for a thousand values. If your data varies in length, that seems like an unnecessary cost.

Comment: That said, the information needs to be retained because the positioning in the array is relevant.

Comment: How is the first `array_dim` 4x4? That looks like 2x4.

Comment: Dim and length is technically redundant in that regard, but it's meant to be an extra sanity check as to whether or not the length of the numpy array and the length of the values in each vector are uniform. If the lengths are *NOT* uniform, it should throw errors, but they didn't match in the R implementation (which was doing delimiter counts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The easy part**

```
df[['array_dim',
    'array_lengths']] = df['numpy_array'].apply([len, 
                                                 lambda x: x.shape])
```

**The arrays expansion**

```py
# Row functions
def new_cols(row):
    '''Generate the relevant columns names'''
    return ['row_{}_col_{}'.format(r,c) for r,c in itertools.product(range(row['numpy_array'].shape[0]), 
                                                                     range(row['numpy_array'].shape[1]))]
def new_vals(row):
    '''Flatten the numpy array'''
    return row['numpy_array'].ravel()

expansion = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(index   = pd.Index(data=[i]),
                                    columns = new_cols(df.loc[i]),
                                    data    = [new_vals(df.loc[i])]) 
                       for i in df.index], axis=0)

   row_0_col_0  row_0_col_1  row_0_col_2  row_0_col_3  row_1_col_0  row_1_col_1  row_1_col_2  row_1_col_3  row_0_col_4  row_0_col_5  ...  row_2_col_6  row_2_col_7  row_3_col_0  row_3_col_1  row_3_col_2  row_3_col_3  row_3_col_4  row_3_col_5  row_3_col_6  row_3_col_7
0     0.012110      0.11211     0.110101      0.10202     0.102010      0.22000     0.020100     0.102200          NaN          NaN  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
1     0.023203      0.22000     0.021000      0.32101     0.103223      0.03231     0.101321     0.102033     0.201123     0.301110  ...      0.12023     0.332202     0.010103     0.301033     0.103032       0.1103     0.130102     0.313121      0.21131      0.12101
2     0.110120      0.11303     0.101201      0.30332     0.023100      0.11100     0.202300     0.011200     0.131200     0.020302  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
```

Variants of the above code with `iterrows` or `itertuples` are possible.

Finally assemble both parts:

```py
df_final = pd.concat([df.drop(columns = 'numpy_array'), expansion], axis=1)

    ID  Binary  Continuous     date1     date2 character  array_dim array_lengths  row_0_col_0  row_0_col_1  ...  row_2_col_6  row_2_col_7  row_3_col_0  row_3_col_1  row_3_col_2  row_3_col_3  row_3_col_4  row_3_col_5  row_3_col_6  row_3_col_7
0  101       0           0  20-01-01  21-01-01      CHAR          2        (2, 4)     0.012110      0.11211  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
1  102       0           2  21-01-01  22-01-01      CHAR          4        (4, 8)     0.023203      0.22000  ...      0.12023     0.332202     0.010103     0.301033     0.103032       0.1103     0.130102     0.313121      0.21131      0.12101
2  103       0           5  22-01-01  23-01-01      CHAR          3        (3, 6)     0.110120      0.11303  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
```

Giving up for now on non vectorized dynamic column generation. The dynamic number of columns is killing my apply attempts. Each row expansion requires its own column index.